# Issue sorting DataTable c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, datatable

Supposing i have the following values in a column in `DataTable`

```
120,00
200,00
201,00
12510,00
```

On sorting them in `ASC ORDER` i am always getting the `12510,00` on top and remaining sort perfectly fine. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it's a string column, you should fill it with the correct type. If that's not possible you can use `decimal.Parse`, for example:

```
tbl = tbl.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(row => decimal.Parse(row.Field<string>("ColumnName")))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

You need to add `using System.Linq`.

If you use a different decimal separator you can use `decimal.Parse(row.Field<string>("ColumnName"), new CultureInfo("de-DE"))`.